# Ruby novice: Writing a method to read mulitple arrays from a file?

Tags: ruby, arrays, methods

I have a file with ten separate columns of data separated by spaces. I have written the following code (and it works), but I feel that there is a much cleaner way to do what I am doing here:

```
#Generate ten separate arrays in which to store the columns
c0 = []; c1 = []; c2 = []; c3 = []; c4 = []; 
c5 = []; c6 = []; c7 = []; c8 = []; c9 = [];

#Append each item in each line to its own array
File.open(filename, 'r').each_line do |line|
  line = line.strip.split(' ')
  c0 << line[0]; c1 << line[1]; c2 << line[2]; c3 << line[3]; c4 << line[4]; 
  c5 << line[5]; c6 << line[6]; c7 << line[7]; c8 << line[8]; c9 << line[9]; 
end
```

I tried to write a method to accomplish this task, but I am essentially clueless on where to start.  I imagine that there is a cleaner way to initialize n-number of arrays than how I have done...what is the 'ruby' way of doing that?  Is it possible to do everything I am doing here in a single method that returns 10 arrays?  Help/hints on how to accomplish this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.open(filename, 'r') do |infile|
  c = infile.lines.map(&:split).transpose
end
```

Now `c` is a two-dimensional array where each row is an array representing a column from the original file so `c[0] = c0` and so on.

EDIT: This is probably a little dense. Some explanation:

`infile.lines` is an array where each element is a line from the file.

`infile.lines.map(&:split)` is short for `infile.lines.map { |line| line.split }`.

`' '` is the default char to split on.

`transpose` turns the columns into rows.

Comment: I tried this on a few separate files. I got the following error: test.rb:7:in `transpose': element size differs (10 should be 9) (IndexError).  Any ideas?

Comment: test.rb:7:in `transpose': element size differs (0 should be 6) (IndexError)  This is an error that returned on a file with 6 columns.

Comment: Try it without transpose and see what you get. The length of each array should be the same.

Comment: Great!  This worked well.  I imagine that when I generated the data, there may be a line that doesn't have the same number of columns (which leads me to believe I should check my data-generating code!)  This is likely responsible for the transpose error.  I made a test file with the same number of items in each row, and all of the code (transpose included) worked on that.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I see what the problem was.  There was a blank line at the bottom of my data file!  (Well, the one with 6 columns anyway).  That error above makes sense now.

Comment: Glad you were able to make it work. Please my edit for more detail on what's happening in there.

Comment: The extra details were very helpful.  Can you use "&:method_name" for any object/method that you want to write shorthand like that?

Comment: I mean, ".map(&:method_name)".  I imagine the method would have to be part of the Array class (or inherit from Array?)

Comment: Notice that I didn't supply any parameters to split. If I were supplying a parameter then I would use the long version with a block: map { |l| l.split(',') }. It's possible to supply parameters in some cases but it becomes unwieldy.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this piece of code helps:

```
   c = []
   File.open(filename, 'r').each_line do |line|
      line = line.strip.split(' ')
      columns = Hash.new
      index=0
      line.each do |column|
        columns[index] = column
        index+=1
      end 
      c.push(columns)
    end
```

Where each column is a Hash with an index by line part, and all lines are stored in a array

Comment: What is part exactly?  I'm getting an undefined variable error.  Sorry, I'm a ruby and programming noob (and have little experience working with hashes).  Thanks!

Comment: sorry, the line is: columns[index] =column.